# How to install clang-tidy on macOS?

Tags: macos, clang-tidy

How do you install *clang-tidy* on macOS?

It seems quite easy to install *clang-format* (using brew) on macOS, but it it seems much harder to install *clang-tidy* without install and building all of clang and building from source. Is there a better option?

Comment: I did not find one, some details here: https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/2/20/installing-clangllvm-on-osx . `brew reinstall llvm --with-toolchain` : `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.0: 5,351 files, 2.8GB, built in 50 minutes 39 seconds` .

Comment: Thanks for the link, I expanded on the articles suggestions and added some background detail.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I don't think there is a really easy way to do this today, here are some details:

- clang comes installed on macOS and is the default compiler, but it does not come installed with clang-format or clang-tidy (or possibly any of the extra tools).
- It's really easy to use brew to install [clang-format](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/clang-format) if you want it: `brew install clang-format`
- There is no clang-tidy brew formula.

As a result it seems like the best way to get clang-tidy on macOS is to simply install all of llvm and then make symlinks for the tools you want to use.

```
brew install llvm
ln -s "$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin/clang-format" "/usr/local/bin/clang-format"
ln -s "$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin/clang-tidy" "/usr/local/bin/clang-tidy"
ln -s "$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin/clang-apply-replacements" "/usr/local/bin/clang-apply-replacements"
```

Alternatively, you could [download](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) the prebuilt binaries and create the same symlinks. It's not a good idea to add all of llvm to your `PATH` because of conflicts with the default clang compiler.

Comment: Will "brew install" add all of llvm to my PATH? --EDIT: No. Running `brew info` says, "llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked...."

Comment: I'm getting `Error: invalid option: --with-toolchain`. Is there a new way to install it?

Comment: If you get `Error: invalid option: --with-toolchain` it worked for me to just run it without that option. ie. `brew install llvm` still installs clang-tidy (and then you can symlink it)

Comment: Warning: the `llvm` install is quite massive

Comment: Also often needed: `ln -s "$(brew --prefix llvm)/share/clang/run-clang-tidy.py" "/usr/local/bin/run-clang-tidy.py"`

Answer (score 8):

you can use `brew install fmenezes/tap/clang-tidy` today

Comment: I'm getting strange errors from this `clang-tidy`:
`error: 'string' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]` (complains about line `#include <string>`).
and I'm not getting such errors when running on linux

Comment: I think this does not work because it uses llvm 14 but current Mac xcode is still on 13.x so there are missing include headers

Comment: Not found in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `brew install llvm`
2. Export the `clang-tidy` bin to your `PATH`.
   If you have `zsh`, add `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"` to your `.zshrc` file.
3. Restart your terminal.